# PageMethods is not defined Exception: Does not call the WebMethod in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webmethod, pagemethods

My WebMethod does not get called by the PageMethod call in my Javascript function. Here's the code:

**EDIT**
The Console says:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: PageMethods is not defined
```

**JS:**

```
    function profilefollowbuttonchange(cn) {
        if (cn.className == "profile-page-owner-follow-button") {
                cn.className = "profile-page-owner-follow-button-active";
                alert("camefollow");
                PageMethods.ToggleFollow("follow", onSuccess, onFailure); //Does not trigger
                alert("camefollow"); //Doesn't get printed
            }

            else {
                cn.className = "profile-page-owner-follow-button";
                alert("cameunfollow");
                PageMethods.ToggleFollow("unfollow", onSuccess, onFailure); //Does not trigger
                alert("cameunfollow"); //Doesn't get printed
            }   
    }

function onSuccess() {
}

function onFailure() {
}
```

**C#:**

```
[WebMethod]
public static void ToggleFollow(string command)
{
       //Does not reach this point. 
}
```

And yes I have added the **EnablePageMethods="true"** tag in the ScriptManager tag.

However, I have used two WebMethods in the same page for two different purposes (Two different names). Could that be the issue? I hardly think so, but what do yall think?

Comment: Tried debugging and checking breakpoint ? Also, put a debugger in your script and check in your browser console for any errors received. Show them up here.

Comment: Why not do it using ajax call?..if its not working this way

Comment: @HarveySpecter Oh the console says "Uncaught ReferenceError: PageMethods is not defined". Why is that?

Comment: @Earthling - Try cyberjog's asnwer first and let me know if it works. Else, we look for another solution .

Comment: @HarveySpecter No mate, it doesn't work either. Very weird. thanks man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem is with your execution sequence of the script and the `ScriptManager`. This means that to make sure the `PageMethods` is recognized by the Javascript code, you need to load the `ScriptManager` first and then fire that Javascript function. So in my logic, a simple change is required here. You need to use `$(document).ready()` here in your script to make sure that `ScriptManager` first into the DOM and then your script is fired. Something like this should help here.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
function profilefollowbuttonchange(cn) {
        if (cn.className == "profile-page-owner-follow-button") {
                cn.className = "profile-page-owner-follow-button-active";
                alert("camefollow");
                PageMethods.ToggleFollow("follow", onSuccess, onFailure); //Does not trigger
                alert("camefollow"); //Doesn't get printed
            }

            else {
                cn.className = "profile-page-owner-follow-button";
                alert("cameunfollow");
                PageMethods.ToggleFollow("unfollow", onSuccess, onFailure); //Does not trigger
                alert("cameunfollow"); //Doesn't get printed
            }   
    }

function onSuccess() {
}

function onFailure() {
}
});
```

Just wrap your script code with `$(document).ready()` and then try it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time mate, but the button become nonfunctional and didn't reach the first alert even :/

Comment: Any messages apppearing in the console for this ?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: This one is easy, Just include in your code, a script reference to `jquery.js` file. You can also use `jquery.min.js`.

Comment: It didn't work, good sir. Thank you for taking the time though. I wonder why it doesn't call the method. There is two other web methods though but I'm sure we can use multiple web methods in one page

Comment: It means that the script is not added properly. Would be good if you can show the source code as well.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have ScriptManager configured on your page?

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="scriptManager" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
    <Scripts>
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="script1.js" />
    </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but sadly it doesn't solve it mate. It says: "Uncaught ReferenceError: PageMethods is not defined" in the console though

Answer (score 0):

In case of overlasting problems, just double check the call from javascript I had there PageMehods instead of PageMethods and I had a Friday afternoon coding blindness :-).